# Highchart marker clickable disable and enable condition base?

Tags: php, highcharts

I developed the TimeLine chart using Highchart i faced new scenario.

I want condition base hover disable/Enable option is it possible.
Ex: I add custom values with serious data. Disable hover that Custom values based if it is possible please help out, lot of problem solved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if possible for disable/enable hover: on marker highchart [not for all].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set individual point's [hover](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.states.hover.enabled) state using the `enabled` flag. You need to set this per point so best to pre-process your data array.
Code:

```
$(function () {
    var $reporting = $('#reporting');

    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Mouse events demo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'On point mouse over or mouse out, the values should be reported in top right'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, {
                y: 106.4,
                marker: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NHH7H/).